# Jenkins is not fetching latest commit

Tags: git, plugins, jenkins, gerrit

I am using `git plugin` in **jenkins** which is using **gerrit** trigger strategy. When job is triggered from **gerrit** then commit ID is always latest.

But when I manually or timer trigger, execute the same job then it is always taking same old commit. I checked the `.git` folder in workspace I got `HEAD` file marked as old commit, It is not checking out the latest commit.

Comment: when you say latest, do you mean the most recent non-merged change?

Comment: @RyJones Yes non-mergerd change from gerrit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one workaround for above problem that we can set one advance strategy of `force clean workspace` in `git plugin`.